WAC - Parameter Management for LinkName Manipulation
I have an Email with an Image content block that has a link a link to Facebook. The link has a title of Facebook and an alias of facebook.
In the Web Analytics Connector (WAC) Parameter Management section, I've done the following configurations.
utm_term=%%=iif(LOWERCASE(TRIM(AttributeValue("linkName"))) == "facebook", "abc", "def")=%%

However, the link is always returning to utm_term=def without any exceptions.
This entire situation is strange because utm_term=%%linkName%% by itself does grab the Alias and add it to the url as utm_term=facebook.
--
My end goal is to not append any of these if the destination is facebook, instagram, etc., but I still want to track the clicks/engagement of customers via Click Exports and Data View so the solution here wouldn't work because it disables tracking entirely, not just the additional parameters.

I can only comment on "why it doesnt work", have no solution, sorry.
AttributeValue() tries to get subscriber data. For that it checks the DE used for send, if nothing is found, all subscribers "profile attributes" etc.
Here are the supported sources: https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue/
You are working in the context of a link, not a subscriber.
That is not supported by AttributeValue() - meaning what you see is that chain of attribute retrieves "finding nothing", which is expected in that scenario, and your code falling back. plain %%linkName%% isnt empty of course.

I think I might need a little more information. From what I can gather:
If LinkName contains facebook.com then append utm_term=facebook, else append utm_term=def
If this is what you are looking for then I would suggest something like this:
%%[ 
SET @LinkName = AttributeValue('LinkName')
SET @Link = 'https://something.com'
IF IndexOf(@LinkName,'facebook') > 0 THEN 
SET @utm_term = 'facebook' ELSE
SET @utm_term = 'def' ENDIF
]%%

<a href="Redirect(Concat(@Link,'?&utm_term',@utm_term))">Link</a>


You can't use an AMP Script Block in parameter manager as far as I know, only In-line snippets. Also there's nothing in AttributeValue('LinkName'), it's null at execution time.
